# Chisel - memory initialization

Tags: memory, chisel

Is the best way to initialize a memory in chisel implementing a `for` loop to write in it ?

```scala
is(s_multiplier){
      when(ready){state := s_ready}
      // Initialization of C memory to 0
      for(i <- 0 to matrixSize - 1){
        for(j <- 0 to matrixSize - 1){
          memC.write(i + j, 0.asSInt((2 * cellSize).W))
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disadvantage of using a for loop is that the above code will try to execute the nested for loops in one clock cycle which is not practical since usually the best case scenario is that you perform one write per clock cycle or use a burst mode mechanism. I would suggest to replace i and j with counters that increment at the tick of the clock and stay in the s_multiplier state till you fill up your matrix.

```
is(s_multiplier){
  when(ready){state := s_ready}
  // Initialization of C memory to 0
  when(counti <= matrixSize -1){ //Initialize counti and countj to 0
    when(countj <= matrixSize - 1){
      memC.write(counti + countj, 0.asSInt((2 * cellSize).W))
      countj := countj + 1.U
    }
    counti <= counti + 1.U
    state := s_multiplier
  }. otherwise{state := S_go_to_some_other_state}
```

Comment: I understand. Do I have to create conti and countj as a `counter`  type ?

Comment: You can declare them as registers that increment every clock cycle. I am not sure as to what you mean by the counter type.

Comment: I was talking about that : https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/util/Counter.html but I'll do it with a register, thanks !

Comment: I have an error : `type mismatch;
[error]  found   : chisel3.Bool
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]         while (countj <= matrixSize){`

Comment: Your MatrixSize -1 is Int type and Counti and Counj are unsigned int type, so just do (matrixsize-1).U instead.

Comment: I have the feeling that the `when .otherwise` structure doesn't reproduce the behavior of nested `for` loops. Because I want the content of the `countj` "loop" to be constantly executed as long as `countj` didn't reach the value of `matrixSize`. What I mean is that there is no branching :/

Comment: I mean a `while` is exactly what I'm looking for, but it seems that it's not possible

Comment: As long as you stay in the s_multiplier state you are effectively running a loop, because the clock keeps ticking constantly and at each clock cycle till you reach your desired matrix size you are going back to the same state and repeating the process

Comment: Oh I see ! Thank you for your explainaitions :)